# Creating bean when program starts and inject it to another bean

Tags: java, spring

I am new to Java and I use Java 15 Spring Boot.

I created a scheduler that will be fired with specific
frequency and make HTTP call to the restful API:

```
@Component
public class Scheduler {

    @Scheduled(cron = "*/5 * * * * *", zone = "US/Eastern")
    public void schedule() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .GET()
                .timeout(Duration.ofMinutes(2))
                .header("accept","application/json")
                .uri(URI.create("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"))
                .build();

        HttpResponse<String> response =  client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());   
        System.out.println(response.body());
    }
}
```

As you can see the schedule function fires every 5 seconds, and HttpRequest created and build each time when the function is executed.

I don't see any reason why the HttpRequest should be created and build each time when the function is executed,
it can be created once when the application is started and inject into another bean.

Here is an example of how I think it should be:

```
@Component
public class Scheduler {

  BuilderRequest request;//injected

    @Scheduled(cron = "*/5 * * * * *", zone = "US/Eastern")
    public void schedule() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

        HttpResponse<String> response =  client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());   
        System.out.println(response.body());
    }
}
```

My question is can I get an example or guide on how can it be implemented?

Comment: If you feel that you want to micro-optimize to save resources, then you've fallen to a beginner's mindset trap. The first code is standard idiomatic Java code, and there's absolutely no reason to inject the request.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly.
You need to create a new spring bean. It is really easy.
Create class with @Configuration annotation and create new bean:

```
@Bean    
public HttpRequest request() {
    return HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .GET()
                .timeout(Duration.ofMinutes(2))
                .header("accept","application/json")
                .uri(URI.create("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"))
                .build();
}
```

And next, in Scheduler use private final HttpRequest httpRequest. And create constructor with httpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

In the above block of code, 90% of the time is spent establishing a connection between the client and the server over TCP and only a fraction of it is spent in creating a request object instance and passing it through client.send(). A better question to ask here should be - Can the connection objects be shared across different runs in the scheduled activity?